# xaml: Change ProgressRingElipseThemeSize for single ProgressRing without defining new Style

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, resourcedictionary, overriding, contenttemplate

My windows phone 8.1 project contains 'Resources' folder with ProgressBar.xaml (overriden ProgressRing style here) and Menu.xaml (templates for flyout items).

My App.xaml look like this:

```
<Application
    x:Class="AppName.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AppName">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Menu.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ProgressBar.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

ProgressBar.xaml contains the exact copy of `<Style TargetType="ProgressRing">` from generic.xaml. This style defines another one inside itself:

```
<Style x:Key="ProgressRingEllipseStyle" TargetType="Ellipse">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{ThemeResource ProgressRingElipseThemeSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{ThemeResource ProgressRingElipseThemeSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource ProgressRingElipseThemeMargin}"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
</Style>

<x:Double x:Key="ProgressRingElipseThemeSize">6.5</x:Double>
```

I am okay with ProgressRingElipseThemeSize = 6.5 all around my application except  flyout items. My template for it from Menu.xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem" 
                x:Key="CustomerFlyoutItem">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid MinWidth="40">
            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Check.png"
                Stretch="None"                           
                Visibility="{Binding IsSelected,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}" />

            <ProgressRing Visibility="{Binding IsLoading,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}"
                        IsActive ="True"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource BekeyContrastSolidColorBrush}"
                        MinHeight="40"
                        MinWidth="40">
                <ProgressRing.Resources>
                    <x:Double x:Key="ProgressRingElipseThemeSize">3</x:Double>
                </ProgressRing.Resources>
            </ProgressRing>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

There I made ProgressRing height and width 40 and I'd like to change the size of ellipses to 3. But overriding `ProgressRingElipseThemeSize` inside `<ProgressRing.Resources>` does not make any changes.

I am sure `ProgressRingElipseThemeSize` is what I should change. If I make changes directly in `<Style TargetType="ProgressRing">` like this

```
<Style x:Key="ProgressRingEllipseStyle" TargetType="Ellipse">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource ProgressRingElipseThemeMargin}"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

MenuFlyoutItem looks perfectly, but obviously other progress rings inside my app are affected which is undesirable.

How can I override `ProgressRingElipseThemeSize` locally for one ProgressRing only without defining a brand new style for ProgressRing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I override ProgressRingElipseThemeSize locally for one ProgressRing only without defining a brand new style for ProgressRing?

You can only override system-level resources in App.xaml. You will need to re-template the control if you only want to change one progress ring.

Comment: Do you mean my only way out is to define entire template directly inside the ProgressRing under the question like `<ProgressRing> <ProgressRing.Style> <Style TargetType="ProgressRing"> <Setter Property="Template"> <Setter.Value> <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressRing"> ... </ControlTemplate> </Setter.Value> </Setter> </Style> </ProgressRing.Style> </ProgressRing>` ?

Comment: Well, yes. Since control templates are usually really big, I'd probably just define the style in the page or app resources, and then reference it as a StaticResource on the controls you want to affect.

Comment: It's a pity there is no more elegant way :(